# How can I define RegEx to remove a particular part in a specified line of code?

Tags: regex, replace

I am attempting to remove .nc1 at the end of a line. I receive .nc1 in batches as a steel fabricator. We run into issues with our files where, line 5 in the example below, has an unnecessary .nc1 extension at the end. Problem I have, is that I cannot simply replace the value as it appears in line 2 as well.

In the example photo I have attached, I am looking to remove line 5 .nc1 extension and keep line 2 as is, .nc1 extension removal will be applied in a batch editing to all of my .nc1 files via find/replace.

```
ST
** BB233.nc1 
  F88 
  BB233 
  BB233.nc1 
  1000
  A992
  1 
  W21X201
```

Change to this

```
ST
** BB233.nc1 
  F88 
  BB233 
  BB233 
  1000
  A992
  1 
  W21X201
```

I was looking into Positive and/or Negative lookahead/lookbehind but didnt have much luck in making it work. I am a novice/lack thereof when it comes to using RegEx.

[image: I am using Text Crawler 3 to help with editing the files]

Comment: It's not clear - why do you want to remove it from line 5 but not from line 2?

Comment: We have automated machines that read the files and we have found that if line 5 has .nc1 at the end, the machine has trouble reading them. Really it should be the base file name. But I was hoping RegEx can identify the particular value I want removed.

Comment: Sometimes, the Line 5, as reflected above, can be found on Line 6. But, most of the time it is line 5.

Comment: Does line 2 always start with something other than the filename? If so, you could just remove `.nc1` when the line consists only of the filename

Comment: I have included the before/after I am seeking to change in the main question. Cheers and thank you.

Comment: Probably easier if you added that info to the question so you can format it properly

Comment: Not sure what your language is but perhaps replace `^(\s*[A-Z]{2}\d{3})\.nc1` with `$1` (or whatever is the appropriate value for replace with the contents of group 1) https://regex101.com/r/NLinBJ/1

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I am using Text Crawler 3 Pro/Free versions. https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html

Comment: So in order to make that work. I needed to select the "Mult-Line Anchors" check box when the "Replace" button is ran. Again, a super novice at this. But @Nick's code did exactly what I needed it to do.

Comment: @ZacharyAlexander good to hear. I'm glad it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Match `.nc1` only at the end of lines starting with whitespace, capturing the part you want to keep and putting it back, effectively deleting `.nc1`

```
Search: ^(\s+.*)\.nc1$
Replace: $1
```

Comment: I put the Search values in the field where "Reg Ex" code goes and the Replace values in "Replace" field in the application Text Crawler 3 It doesnt appear to result anything. I am probably not implementing it right?

Comment: Try replacing `\s` with a space character. Also, your tool may require `\1` instead of `$1`. Try some combinations.

Comment: https://www.loom.com/share/7968cae026d046739ff62b8d753160e7